# Getting a dataframe in certain format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in this format right now

[image]

I Want transform the dataframe in the format given below

[image]

I tried few ways like pivot_table, transform etc. but not able to get a solution.

How can i archive this?

Comment: Please provide an [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Try via `set_index()` and `unstack()`:

```
out=df.set_index('Type').unstack().to_frame().T
```

Finally use `map()`:

```
out.columns=out.columns.map('_'.join)
```

output of `out`:

```
    Total_A     Total_B     Total_C     Available_A     Available_B     Available_C
0   11          22              33      1                   2           3
```

Comment: If it solves your query then pls try considering accepting this answer....Thanks **:)**